# How to append an object to each item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I am trying to append an object to an array, but `cart[i]['items'][j][order]` is not getting set properly.

When logging `cart[i]['order']` it returns an `Object`.

The cart is of the form:

```
[{
  "order": {
    "amtSubTotal": 3812.8900000000003,
    "noPo": "Default P.O."
  },
  "items": [{
    "adjustments": { "isCustom": "N" }, 
    "lineNote": { "noteLine": "" }
  },{
    "adjustments": { "isCustom": "N" }, 
    "lineNote": { "noteLine": "" }
  }]
}]
```

**Expected Result**

```
[{
  "order": { "amtSubTotal": 3812.8900000000003,"noPo": "Default P.O." },
  "adjustments": { "isCustom": "N" }, 
  "lineNote": { "noteLine": "" }
  }, {
  "order": { "amtSubTotal": 3812.8900000000003,"noPo": "Default P.O." },
  "adjustments": { "isCustom": "N" }, 
  "lineNote": { "noteLine": "" }
}]
```

**Code**

```
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart-data'));
let i = 0, j = 0, l = cart.length;
let nData = [];
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  let m = cart[i]['items'].length;
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {                                                      // Spreading data {...data[i]} created a shallow copy bug
    cart[i]['items'][j].push({"order": cart[i]['order']}); // Try using JSON methods instead
    nData.push(cart[i]['items'][j]);
  }
}
```

**Alternate Attempt**

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  let m = cart[i]['items'].length;
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    // cart[i]['items'][j]['order'] = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(cart[i]['order'])); // Try using JSON methods instead
    nData.push(cart[i]['items'][j]);
  }
}

console.log(nData); // order data not appended to cart[i]['items'][j]
```

How can I add this object to each `cart[i]['items'][j]` element?

Comment: Can you show how `cart ` looks like

Comment: Please post a sample of `cart` data structure. You don't need to post 100+ items in the array just a few of thems will do.

Comment: @brk Now addded.

Comment: @palaѕн Now added.

Comment: update with expected result..

Comment: @SarathAntony updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with destructuring and map as below.
(In the arrow function argument, destructure `order` and `items`, use `map` to over items and add the contents of order.)

```js
const update = ([{ order, items }]) => items.map(itm => ({ order: {...order}, ...itm }));

const data = [
  {
    order: {
      amtSubTotal: 3812.8900000000003,
      noPo: "Default P.O."
    },
    items: [
      {
        adjustments: { isCustom: "N" },
        lineNote: { noteLine: "" }
      },
      {
        adjustments: { isCustom: "N" },
        lineNote: { noteLine: "" }
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(update(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You code generate a error on push of `cart[i]['items'][j].push(...)` remove a `[j]`

Try this:

```js
let carts = [{
  order: {
    amtSubTotal: 3812.8900000000003,
    noPo: "Default P.O."
  },
  items: [{
    adjustments: { "isCustom": "N" }, 
    lineNote: { "noteLine": "" }
  },{
    adjustments: { "isCustom": "N" }, 
    lineNote: { "noteLine": "" }
  }]
}];

nData = [];

carts.forEach((cart, idx1) => {
  cart['items'].forEach((item, idx2) => {
    item.order = cart.order;
    nData.push(item)
  })
});

console.log(nData);
```

[try this pen](https://codepen.io/mponzo/pen/oNXmErK?editors=0010)

Comment: With this `nData` takes the form `[{...},{...}]` instead of `[{...}]`.

Comment: I've added an example of the `cart-data`.

Comment: I'm confused. When I `console.log(nData[0])` it does not show up, but does return when I `console.log(nData[0]['order'])`.

Comment: work, try this pen: https://codepen.io/mponzo/pen/oNXmErK?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Use map() to modify your object on each iteration and to add items object's properties
iterate through key values `for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(itemObj)`

Try running this snippet. 
Ive added second item in cart for testing purpose

```js
let cart=[{"order": {"amtSubTotal": 3812.8900000000003,"noPo": "Default P.O."},"items": [{"adjustments": { "isCustom": "N" }, "lineNote": { "noteLine": "" }},{"adjustments": { "isCustom": "N" }, "lineNote": { "noteLine": "" }}]},{"order": {"amtSubTotal": 3112.8900000000003,"noPo": "Default R.O."},"items": [{"adjustments": { "isCustom": "Y" }, "lineNote": { "noteLine": "1" }},{"adjustments": { "isCustom": "N" }, "lineNote": { "noteLine": "5" }}]}]
let result=cart.map( orderObj =>{
   let obj={order:orderObj.order};
   orderObj.items.forEach( itemObj =>{
      for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(itemObj))
          obj[key]=value;
   });
   return obj
}); 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Maybe close... items properties shouldn't be nested in orders when logging `result`.